# CSS: Align with text

Tags: css

I am a total Newbie when it comes to CSS, I am using code copied from another program so please excuse me if this is a simple or weird question.

In my table I have this code:

```
<td colspan="4" align="center">Rate this picture: 

<div id="$ratingsDiv" class="rating" align="center">&nbsp;</div></td>
```

and in the css file I have found this:

```
.rating {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 2em;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.rating:after {
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

div.rating div.on a {
    background-position: 0 -16px;
}
div.rating div.hover a,
div.rating div a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}
```

Two questions:
1 - How do I get it aligned in the center of my `<td>` ?
2 - How can I align it with my "Rate this picture:" text?

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/jcbq9osf/

Comment: Fiddle buddy thats helps us to see whats going on with your code.

Comment: Little tip for you. Don't use tables for layout.

Comment: Benjamin, you want me to post my entire CSS file or?
Alex, Got a good tut for tables without CSS? I googled and found a decent tut but it does not explain, for example, how to do colspans...

Comment: text is already aligned in the center of div. to be more helpful a jsfiddle or more markup code would be very useful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jcbq9osf/

Comment: ok, the picture and the "rate this picture" text look aligned at the center of the div. So what you need exactly?

Comment: It's not aligned: http://postimg.org/image/pqkb85p33/ As you can see there it says "Rate this picture:" and then the stars come way below...

Comment: @Ryan Try adding `margin: 0em 2em;` to `.rating` to remove the top and bottom margin (space) - http://jsfiddle.net/8kpe6wyd/

Comment: Maybe it's only me, but I don't get *what* you want to be aligned to *what*. It's not clear in your original post, because you keep saying "it" instead of specifying what has to be aligned.

Comment: Firstly, laying out things with tables is never a clean job. Divs would have made your job 100 times easier. Is this what you are trying to archive ? http://jsfiddle.net/jcbq9osf/2/ @Ryan

Comment: @arty, everything is working fine, except the stars script is screweing everything up - and I would love to do it with just divs but I don't really know how

Answer (score 0):

try this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jcbq9osf/6/)**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="rate-text">Rate this Application</div>
        <div id="rate1" class="rating">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have updated the  CSS

```
body html{
    margin:0 auto;
}
body{
    background: red;
}
.wrapper{
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    display: block;
    background:blue;
    width:30%;
    margin:0 auto;
 }
.rate-text{
    margin:0 auto; 
    color:#000;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align:top; 
    text-align:center;
    display:inline;
}
```

if you found alignment issues try to change the width of `.container`. 
let me know if its solved your problem

Comment: It made it a bit better, but the stars still come on the next line instead of in the same line as the text...